# Formula which gives 1 for all positive integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a mathematical formula which outputs 1 for all positive integers of x?... that doesn't contain any mods or floor fucntion..

I tried to look for a function like this for a long time, but all possible solution I found includes either the mod fucntion or the floor fucntion, which is not what I'm looking for. Can someone help me please, thank you guys!

Comment: Um..... $f(x) =1$.

Comment: ... or $f(x) = x^0$ or $f(x) = \frac xx$ or $f(x) = x -(x-1)$ or ...... or $f(x) = \sqrt{(x+1)^2 -x^2- 2x}$ or....

Comment: As others have said, the constant $f(x)=1$ does what you want.  If you want something more elaborate, try $g(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$.

Comment: @lulu but sin(2pi)=0

Comment: @Karam  Absolutely, thanks.   $\cos (2\pi x)$ it is.

Comment: $1-\lceil \{ |x| \} \rceil$, technically it does not contain mod or floor function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there is.
It needs to be a function that isn't dependent on any variable inputted; one example is
$$f(x) = 1,$$
because you can easily notice that for any inputted $x$ it returns one.

Another example is $(variable)^0$.